# Debug php executed from rabbitmq queue with xdebug

Tags: php, rabbitmq, xdebug

I'm trying to debug PHP code executed by a RabbitMQ consumer.

xdebug is working fine in both CLI and http, but it fails when something is executed from a queue. I have set the following trace:

```
ini_get("xdebug.idekey")  
ini_get("xdebug.remote_host")
ini_get("xdebug.remote_connect_back")  
ini_get("xdebug.remote_mode"). 
ini_get("xdebug.remote_autostart") 
php_ini_loaded_file()
getenv("XDEBUG_CONFIG")
```

It prints:

```
"" 
localhost
1
req
0

/etc/php5/cli/php.ini    

xdebug.idekey=sublime.xdebug 
xdebug.remote_host=10.5.223.108 
xdebug.remote_connect_back=0 
xdebug.remote_mode=req xdebug.remote_autostart=1
```

So the problem seems to be that it is ignoring the environment variable `XDEBUG_CONFIG` and is using the values in the cli ini file. I don't have permissions to modify the ini file, and the `XDEBUG_CONFIG` variable works fine when executing something via CLI.

Any ideas why `XDEBUG_CONFIG` is being ignored when the code is executed from a queue?

Comment: need to know more about your mq consumer.  how are you starting it?  Are you sure it has environment variable XDEBUG_CONFIG ?

Comment: @chugadie I might be wrong, but is that really relevant? It all ends up calling `php my_code.php`, and in my_code.php getenv("XDEBUG_CONFIG") returns the correct values, so the php interpreter that runs xdebug has access to it, I thought that was the only relevant thing. The mq system is mostly external to me and I know little about it

Comment: Hello fuaa, how did you consume messages from your queue, I mean who is this "RabbitMQ consumer" ? Not a PHP cli ?

Answer (score 0):

#### Xdebug and RabbitMQ consumer commands

To make your IDE aware of the connection you need to prefix the command with the environment variable:

`XDEBUG_CONFIG="put-here-your-value" php my-script.php`